# display block formatting issue

Tags: css, xpages

I am trying to show/hide   on click of some image, but the formatting of the tr is going terribly wrong. Am I doing something wrong?? Attached is the result. I have also tried adding custom formatting but wont worked either. [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:div style="position:relative;">
    <xp:table id="table1">
        <xp:tr style="width:100%">
            <xp:td>a</xp:td>
            <xp:td>b</xp:td>
            <xp:td>c</xp:td>
            <xp:td>d</xp:td>
            <xp:td>e</xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr id="tr0" style="width:100%">
            <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="Vnr">
                </xp:comboBox></xp:td>
            <xp:td><xp:comboBox id="comboBox1"></xp:comboBox></xp:td>
            <xp:td id="td1"><xp:image url="./add.png" id="image23">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false"
                id="eventHandler3">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var tr0 = document.getElementById("#{id:tr1}");
tr0.style.display = "block";
    ]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:image>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var tr0 = document.getElementById("#{id:tr1}");
tr0.style.display = "block";]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr id='tr1' style="width:100%;display:none;">
            <xp:td>
                <xp:comboBox id="comboBox2"></xp:comboBox>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:comboBox id="comboBox3" style=""></xp:comboBox>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:image url="./add.png" id="image1">

                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false"
                        id="eventHandler1">
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var tr0 = document.getElementById("#{id:tr2}");
tr0.style.display = "block";
    ]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:image>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr id="tr2" style="display:none;">
            <xp:td>
                <xp:comboBox id="comboBox4"></xp:comboBox>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:comboBox id="comboBox5"></xp:comboBox>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:image url="./add.png" id="image2">


                </xp:image>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr></xp:table></xp:div></xp:view>
```

Comment: The CSS property *display* will not be inherited. Try to use *visibilty:hidden* instead.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but can you try using `table-row` for `display` property. So your code would be like `tr0.style.display = "table-row"`.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete/empty the display style class with

```
var tr = document.getElementById("#{id:tr1}");
tr.style.display = "";
```

Then you get the default behavior: a table row in this case.

Comment: @user3379225: you accepted the answer and some hours later you un-accepted it. What is the reason? Do you have trouble to get it to work for an older browser version or do you have some other issue with removing the property "display" from attribute "style"?